# Fill Days, Months & Years Options Grayed Out in MS Excel

Tags: excel, autofill

I am trying to fill dates in series and the options like "Fill Days", "Fill Months", "Fill Years" are grayed out in the pop-up. How to enable that?

[image: Screenshot of the Excel sheet.]

Comment: Most likely that date is being seen as text. Is the cell formatted as text, or are your regional settings set to something like US that doesn't use dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 0):

thank you techmonk your comment made me find the answer
the excel recognis the date written as a text
to fix that sent months to be in letters insted or number then excel will recognis it as date then you can customize it to be in numbers.

or you can go to data and press text to columns and press next on delimited and then remove and ticked box then press next then choose date and the format you desire

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).